Best Practice to parse swaps from raw transaction data?
What is the best practice to parse for swaps from raw transaction data?
I was told to parse the messageLogs but then I encountered a weird TX which had 6 bundled swaps but the swap logs in messageLogs were only 4.
This is the TX: https://solscan.io/tx/4Lg7TRnT1sY716F2fndPStfqDMFWSmqMuYhQ64yNM4wuYeRJ1xibNvRhfpNEsjkjUn8FXFCDACeRHNeuWY9wUwWB
My next thought was to parse the transaction.instructions array, filtering for programId and decoding the data. I did that, i got correct values for the purchased tokens but incorrect values for the sol spent. (if anyone can explain why that is i'd appreciate it).
So, what's left is a combination of parsing the transaction.instructions in combination with the meta.innerInstructions, which is quite a task.
So I wanted some confirmation from more experienced folks on the right way to parse for swaps or any kind of actions in raw TX data.
Thank you

Each swap platform has its own docs on how should instructions for transaction look like, or what is your goal to achieve here? Are you using pumpfun api for swaps?

Regardless of goal or platform, the question is more generic on how to approach parsing of a raw Solana transaction.
